# How to make a larger iPad by changing screen and case?

Tags: ipad, screen, hacking

Do you know of any attempt to hack an iPad and make it larger by using a larger screen and a custom case?
I know iPad screen can be reused : [recycling retina iPad screen as monitor](https://hackaday.com/2019/07/18/put-those-ipad-displays-to-work-with-this-edp-adapter/).
But I'd need the opposite : fit a noname screen+digitizer in an iPad.
I would prefer a solution for first generations of iPad. But last gen will be fine too as usb-c native mirroring on external display will probably help.

EDIT
there are ligthning or usb-c adaptor adapters where you can plug usb trackpad but they need at least iPadOs 13.4.
So you'll need :

- iPad 5th gen
- iPad mini 4th gen
- iPad Air 2
- any iPad pro

Answer (score 1):

Many iPad models featuring the Lightning connector allow you to connect an external display over HDMI using a Lightning Digital AV Adapter. Recent iPad models featuring USB-C or Thunderbolt connectors allows you to connect a display without using an adapter.

As for the touch digitizer, it is possible to connect it using the USB protocol to for example a recent iPad having a USB-C connector. Realistically you want to use a USB-C dongle/dock that allows you to have USB in (for the touch digitizer), DisplayPort/HDMI out (for the external display) and power in (for charging the iPad).

You could create a custom case that holds the iPad, has the cable connected to the iPad, an adapter/dongle/dock, and an external screen featuring an appropriate interface (HDMI, USB-C/DisplayPort, depending on iPad model) and USB touch-digitizer. Such a custom case would most probably be quite large.

You cannot connect a larger screen to the internal display connector inside the iPad, unless that larger screen has been made explicitly for the purpose of being connected to that connector. As far as I know, such a display does not exist. Note that even such a larger display could only be physically larger - it cannot have a larger resolution than the original iPad display.